# Loading store dynamically based on visible page data for Ext.grid.Panel column

Tags: extjs, dynamic, extjs4, store, renderer

Below is a renderer for an Ext.grid.Panel column.  Suppose contactStore has 2,000 values in it and all I care about is the name of the record based on the id (value parameter in this case), and my grid only has 25 rows/records in it for the page I'm on.  How can I dynamically get the store so that I grab the relevant associated records (based on the foreign key) of the id of my grid column, rather than loading all 2,000 records?  Is there a way to load the store and then in the callback, somehow have this "renderer" function display the values after the callback succeeded?

```
columns: [{
```

...

```
}, {
    header: 'Contact Name',
    flex: 1,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'contact_id',        
    renderer: function(value) {
        var contactStore = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('Contacts');
        return contactStore.getById(value).get('full_name');
    }
}, {
```

Comment: I think you will have to hack either the renderer or the table view. In the first case, that would probably mean that the contact store will make 25 requests per page load; have you considered that? In the later case, do you have some mean to make the contact store load the 25 random contacts at once?

Comment: I've read about a few different ways of doing this. (1) having a seperate store and loading that store based on the data in the page (2) loading the names as additional fields in the grid store (3) using associated models and getting the names for JUST the records we care about from the associated store(s) ........ although I couldn't find examples of the others .... What would you recommend Rixo?

Comment: If you have control over the server, I would definitely add the name field to the grid model. That would save you a bunch of request and it would make your code a lot simpler. Hence more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `collectData(records, startIndex)` in the `viewConfig` for that:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    (...)
    viewConfig: {
        //this method needs to be adjusted
        collectData: function(records, startIndex) {
            var me = this;
            //we can use a custom function for this
            if (me.onBeforeCollectData) {
                me.onBeforeCollectData(records);
            }            
            var data = me.superclass.collectData.call(me, records, startIndex);
            return data;
        },

        onBeforeCollectData: function(records) {
            var newExtraParams = [];
            var oldExtraParams;
            var needToLoadStore = false;
            var contactStore = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('Contacts');         

            if (contactStore) {
                oldExtraParams = contactStore.oldExtraParams;
            } else {
                //don't use autLoad: true, this will be a local store
                contactStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    storeId:'Contacts',
                    (...)                   
                });
                needToLoadStore = true;
            }

            for (var x in records) {
                //contact_id is read out here
                var param = records[x].get('contact_id');
                if (param) {
                    if (needToLoadStore == false && Ext.Array.contains(oldExtraParams, param) == false) {
                        needToLoadStore = true;
                    }
                    newExtraParams.push(param);
                }                
            }           

            if (needToLoadStore == true) {
                //we use this to load the store data => because of async: false property
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    scope: this,
                    //this is for synchronous calls
                    async: false,
                    url: (...),
                    method: (...),
                    params: newExtraParams,
                    success: function (res, opt) {
                        var responseObj = Ext.decode(res.responseText, false);
                        contactStore.loadData(responseObj); //or deeper in the responseObj if needed
                        contactStore.oldExtraParams = newExtraParams;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for answering .. I've read about a few different ways of doing this.  (1) having a seperate store and loading that store based on the data in the page (2) loading the names as additional fields in the grid store (3) using associated models and getting the names for JUST the records we care about from the associated store(s) ........ although I couldn't find examples of the others .... What would you recommend Alexander?

Comment: I was thinking of something like that. I wouldn't create the contact store each time, but rather attach it to the view. Don't forget to trigger the store loading with the `extraParams` in `onBeforeCollectData`. Finally you need a callback that calls the `refresh` method of the view once the contact store is loaded. Now, the fun part is that `collectData` is called in `refresh`, so you need to add a test to prevent `onBeforeCollectData` from being called when `refresh` is called from the callback, or you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: @MacGyver I would recommend the (2) because then you need only give a custom `renderer` to the `column` with `return record.get('contactName');` I would use (1) If you use this dynamic store on more columns or the backend for the grid store load webservice can't easily add this field to the store.

Comment: adjusted the answer with @rixo's suggestions

Comment: Great, thanks!  That's much easier.  And I don't need any hacks.  I'll just add record 'name' fields in my model for each of the FK fields, in addition to the id.  I'm thinking a normal person would want to sort based on the name as well, and not the id, after it's rendered.